# Using fscanf to read line by line from input file

Tags: c, scanf

I am reading in from a file that has 15 features separated by the '|' symbol. I am using:  `while(fscanf(file, "%*d|%s|%*s|%s|%*d|%*s|%*d|%*s|%*s|%*f|%*f|%*s|%*s|%*f|%*f", &name, &state)==2)` but when I ran gdb on it I realized it never actually entered the loop. I used `%*d/s` because it tells `fscanf` to skip over these values correct? I only want to read in 2 values of the entire line from the input, the two %s near the beginning. 
Any suggestions on how to fix? Sorry for not optimal formatting.

Comment: The `'*'` modifier is the *assignment suppression* operator telling `fscanf` to *read and discard* the characters that would otherwise be matched by the conversion specifier. No pointer argument is required and any characters matched and discarded are not included in the match-count returned. I would read the entire line into a buffer with `fgets` and then parse the information from the buffer with `sscanf`.

Comment: For further help, please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it sits, your question will likely be closed.

Comment: `%s` won't stop at a pipe symbol; `%[^|]` would.

Comment: I recommend using `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` to read the line, then consider parsing the line with `sscanf()`, or maybe using ad hoc methods.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so would I need 15 pointers for sscanf? I only wish to know the strings of 2/15 features.

Comment: No, works just the same -- but since you read with `fgets`, a failure in parsing (e.g. *matching* or *input* failure) doesn't screw up your loop control.

Comment: @cap, If you are still have problems, if you will edit your question and post a couple lines of sample data, I'll see if I can help you with a short example to read them and parse what you need from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still stuck, a short example may help. Looking at your attempted format string, e.g.

```
"%*d|%s|%*s|%s|%*d|%*s|%*d|%*s|%*s|%*f|%*f|%*s|%*s|%*f|%*f"
```

You appear to want to save the 2nd and 4th fields as string values in `name` and `state`.

Immediately I suspect you use of `&name, &state` is incorrect, because, presuming you have declared `name` and `state` as character arrays sufficiently sized to hold the data in the 2nd and 4th fields, `name` and `state` are already pointers (see: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)), so there is no need for an `'&'` preceding the variable names. If they were not declared as character arrays (or as pointers to arrays and allocated sufficient memory), your parse would fail anyway due to incompatible types.

Next, why it is so important to read the entire line with `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` and then parse with `sscanf()` instead of using `fscanf()`:

1. your read will fail if there is any *matching* or *input* failure with any one of the 15 fields; and
2. you only care about the 2nd and 4th fields -- there is no need to make your read dependent on the successful parse of 15 fields when you only care about two of them.

So rather than having to worry about a correct match of 15 fields, you only need worry about 4 -- you don't care about the rest of the line after the 4th field.

Putting a small example together with randomly generated data (adjust the buffer sizes as needed for your data), you could do something like the following to parse the 2nd and 4th fields as strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FLDW   32   /* max field width */
#define MAXC 1024   /* max chars in line */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC],     /* line buffer */
        name[FLDW],     /* storage for name */
        state[FLDW];    /* storage for state */

    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line of input */
        /* parse 2nd & 4th fields as strings - you don't care about rest */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%*d|%31[^|]|%*[^|]|%31[^|]", name, state) == 2) {
            buf[strcspn (buf, "\n")] = 0;   /* trim \n from buf */
            /* output line with parsed name and state to right */
            printf ("%s  =>  name: %s, state: %s\n", buf, name, state);
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the use of a *field-width* modifier to protect the array bounds of `name` and `state` with `%31[^|]`. The use of `strcspn` was just to trim the `'\n'` from the end of `buf` so `name` and `state` values would print on the same line following outputting `buf`. If you are not printing `buf`, then you don't need that call at all for parsing purposes)

**Example Use/Output**

Minimum data generated matching your format string. Parsing the 2nd and 4th values would yield the desired strings in `name` and `state`, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/fgetssscanf dat/field15pipes.txt
01|8a|0b|6c|82|1d|33|5e|4f|7.|0.|4g|3h|7.|5.  =>  name: 8a, state: 6c
01|9a|5b|0c|42|1d|93|3e|9f|8.|0.|5g|4h|6.|5.  =>  name: 9a, state: 0c
01|4a|5b|7c|22|0d|23|1e|1f|7.|2.|1g|5h|7.|7.  =>  name: 4a, state: 7c
01|8a|2b|5c|72|1d|53|6e|2f|1.|1.|8g|0h|7.|6.  =>  name: 8a, state: 5c
11|4a|6b|5c|92|2d|73|0e|6f|4.|2.|2g|7h|2.|4.  =>  name: 4a, state: 5c
01|2a|6b|0c|02|1d|83|0e|2f|5.|2.|9g|4h|3.|8.  =>  name: 2a, state: 0c
31|1a|0b|0c|72|2d|13|3e|3f|9.|0.|2g|5h|6.|9.  =>  name: 1a, state: 0c
01|8a|3b|7c|92|1d|93|3e|9f|6.|1.|4g|4h|8.|3.  =>  name: 8a, state: 7c
11|1a|4b|7c|42|2d|73|0e|5f|7.|0.|0g|5h|1.|7.  =>  name: 1a, state: 7c
21|8a|6b|9c|22|2d|23|2e|1f|9.|0.|1g|6h|6.|8.  =>  name: 8a, state: 9c
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: could you explain more exactly what the format specifiers are for sscanf?

Comment: Sure [scanf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) Take the time to read it. It will probably take an hour to digest (write sample code to test while reading), but that hour spent will save you hundreds of hours of frustration later. Basics, all conversion specifiers consume leading whitespace EXCEPT `'%c"` and `"%[...]"`. When filling arrays, ALWAYS use a *maximum field-width* modifier to protect your array bounds. `scanf` does not consume the trailing `'\n'` (also whitespace) so make sure you handle that appropriately.If you are stuck, comment again.